# Displaying text in center of a drop down list

Tags: html, css

Here is my http://jsfiddle.net/JvC9v/4/

Click http://jsfiddle.net/JvC9v/4/show to see it in full page.
I am trying to display the text between the `<option> </option>` to the center of the drop down list. i.e I want the text "Item 1" to appear in the center.

I tried it with the code

```
option {
text-align: center;
}
```

I did not succeed. Can anyone suggest me how to achieve the same.

Comment: To my knowledge, this wouldn't be possible in pure CSS.. you are pretty limited when it comes to styling `select` boxes.. you can do this though.. http://jsfiddle.net/MHUYA/

Comment: @JoshC the second fiddle is kind like a hack. the text inside option box may be small. in that case it won't look good. i am looking for something like text-align: centre that can make any text to appear at exact centre

Comment: Yea - so it goes back to what I originally stated.. it's not possible. `select` boxes are extremely hard to style.. even if you could style them, all browsers have different defaults.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correct, is this what you are trying to achieve? See working example **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/JvC9v/5/show/)**.

```
select {
     width: 100%;
     text-align: center;
     padding-left: 50%;
}
```

Comment: its not in exact centre

Comment: Yeah, and it varies with different browsers. But I think this is the far as you can go without doing hacks/custom dropdowns etc.

Answer (score 1):

try this in your c

```
select{ text-align-last:center;}
```

this will center all the text in the drop down to center. but i'm afraid it only work with chrome browser.

Answer (score 0):

```
select {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
enter code here**strong text**<select  >
<option>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;--Drop Down Menu--</option>
<option>Option one</option>
<option>Option Two</option>
<option>Option Three</option>
```

Comment: This will not work in all cases e.g. different views (mobile, tablet, desktop)... you should use CSS styles, if you want make it nice